# Who are those users with long membership and near-none posts?

Tags: discussion

I sometimes see users who have been a registered user for a few years, and nevertheless they are making their  post for the first time.

It is not a problem, but I feel it strange, and am curious to know if some unusual thing is going on. Who are those people? How does that happen? Have they remembered Stack Overflow (with their registered user names and passwords) for years, and have made their first posts over the years?

Comment: They could simply be using their account to vote on posts and mark questions as favourite. There's so much information available on SO already, so there's often no need to post a new question.

Comment: They could have also posted a lot of junk questions / answers that got deleted.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi Your edit may have made it better, and I have no intention to further change it, but when you want to ask an attribute of a person in English, you use *what* even if the subject is a human. *A: What is John? B: A student*. You use *who* when you are asking the identity of a person. *A: Who is that student? B: It's John.* I intended to ask the attribute of those users and not the identity (in the SO world), which I already know.

Comment: @sawa, thank you for this clarification. I admit I jumped at "What are those users" because that looked pejorative to me, but if it's an appropriate use of the English language then I stand corrected. Maybe something based around "why" would be a good middle-ground, e.g. "Why are there users with long membership...".

Comment: I think "who" is exactly what you mean  When people say "Who are xes?" they mean what are the characteristics of the group. It is not the same as "who is y?".

Comment: @Elin Sorry, but your information is not reliable to me because you even made a grammatical mistake in the comment, which is directly related to the construction in question. It should be *... they mean what the characteristics of the group are*.

Comment: Not sure what mistake you see, but okay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a lot of users only reading answers. With an account you can save your favorites so you do not have to search them over and over again. Also these users can give something back (without answering questions) if they have enought reputation they can up-vote the questions and answers which helped them.

And then after a time, they have a question that was not asked before and they post their first question. Or they see a question they know an answer to an write it down, because they see no one else is doing it.

Answer (score 5):

I have also some 101 rep accounts on differnt Stack Exchange sites. It was just because I wanted to ask something, but I found a solution somewhere else, or I asked a question which never raised the attation of other users.